# What is my name abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations

My name is 'Ehsan Shirzadi'.
I want to know whether my name abbreviation is E.S or E.Sh?

Comment: What? I can't understand what's your mean.

Comment: It's a joke related to a teen pop star in the US.

Answer (score 3):

In English, unlike Arabic or some Eastern European languages, which use single letters for sounds like 'sh' or 'ch', many sounds are written in letter pairs, as I've had to do just now.

No person whose surname was Charles, Sharp, or Django would think twice about using the first letter as the initial for their surname.

I may be wrong, but to insist on using two letters would be culturally setting yourself apart, and may be seen negatively.

Comment: Is there any reference for this purpose? I'm a persian guy and in my language we have a letter for 'Sh'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reference'? And as a Persian, would you insist on 'A for 'Attar in English?